# Can I auto collect a list of function by C Macro

Tags: c, gcc

I want to auto collect a list of functions begin FUN_BEGIN() & FUN_END() macro, if I write it as:

```
FUN_BEGIN()

FUN_DEFINE(f1) {
    printf("f1\n"); }

FUN_DEFINE(f2) {
    printf("f2\n"); }

FUN_DEFINE(f3) {
    printf("f3\n"); }

FUN_END()
```

The code will expand as below:

```
static bool f1(void) 
{
    printf("f1\n");
}

static bool f2(void)
{
    printf("f2\n");
}


static bool f3(void)
{
    printf("f3\n");
}


void global_fun(void)
{
    f1();
    f2();
    f3();
}
```

Can I releasize that?

Comment: Writing code like this is a really bad idea. Never re-invent the C language using obscure macros. It will make your code unreadable, unmaintainable and error-prone, for zero gain. Spontaneously, this just sounds like yet another a needlessly complex solution without any actual problem to solve.

Comment: I use this only in my C Unit test framwork. Using FUN_DEFINE() macro can auto collect a list of test() functions. So I can focus on writing test function body, needn't think about where & how to call it. In fact, I have test nneonneo's answer, it works! Do you think is it right? Or you have any other suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion would be to rewrite it entirely using plain arrays of function pointers. To me, there is no obvious reason why you would ever need macros to create lists of functions.

Comment: Alternative solution posted, in 100% standard C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses constructors to add to a list, permitting the exact syntax you used.

```
#define FUN_BEGIN() struct __fun_list { \
    struct __fun_list *next; \
    bool (*f)(void); \
} *head = NULL; \
static void globals_list_add(bool (*f)(void)) { \
    /* add f to the linked list... */ \
}

#define FUN_DEFINE(f) static bool f(void);\
    static void __attribute__((constructor)) __construct_##f(void) {\
        globals_list_add(f); \
    } \
    static bool f(void)

#define FUN_END() void global_fun(void) { \
    struct __fun_list *cur; \
    for(cur = head; cur; cur = cur->next) { \
        cur->f(); \
    } \
}
```

Note the constructors are not necessarily called in the order they are declared, so you may need to use `__LINE__` in the macro to sort the list by the line number of the definition.

Comment: __attribute__((constructor)) can execute function before main(), and initial a link, That's just what I want! I have test the code, exactly work! good idea & thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
typedef bool (*func_t) (void);

// ...place function prototypes anywhere in scope

funct_t test_functions [] = 
{
  &f1,
  &f2,
  &f3
};

#define TEST_FUNCTIONS_N (sizeof(test_functions) / sizeof(funct_t))

void global_fun(void)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<TEST_FUNCTIONS_N; i++)
  {
    test_functions[i]();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to put your defines in a separate file

`funcs.def`:

```
FUN_DEFINE(f1) {
    printf("f1\n"); }

FUN_DEFINE(f2) {
    printf("f2\n"); }

FUN_DEFINE(f3) {
    printf("f3\n"); }
```

then in a different source file, do something like

```
#define FUN_DEFINE(name) static bool name(void)
#include "funcs.def"
#undef FUN_DEFINE

void global_fun(void) {
#define FUN_DEFINE(name) name();
#include "funcs.def"
#undef FUN_DEFINE
}
```

There's a name for this approach, but I can't remember it offhand.

Comment: You're thinking of X-Macros.

Comment: Nevertheless, you'll end up creating code that looks like this, which I don't think is the desired result: `void global_fun(void) { f1(); { printf("f1\n"); } f2(); { printf("f2\n"); } f3(); { printf("f3\n"); } }`

Comment: One description of X-macros (without using that name) is found at [Enums, Strings, and Laziness](http://labs.mudynamics.com/2007/01/03/enums-strings-and-laziness/).

Comment: good idea! But global_fun() expand will be NOT right, it's like:
void global_fun(void) { f1(); {printf("f1\n");} f2(); {printf("f2\n");} f3(); {printf("f3\n"); }
}  It's NOT my want.

Comment: Ah yes, good point about the rest of the function expanding into it too.